# Jsoup adds extra newline

Tags: html, jsoup

When I parse this one-line html and convert it back

```
Jsoup.parse("h<span class='cool'>un</span>d", "").body().html()
```

I get an extra newline after th 'h'

```
"h\n<span class=\"cool\">un</span>d"
```

How could I avoid this from happening? Because it adds an extra space when showing in a browser.

Comment: Have you tried text-replace `\n` to empty string?

Comment: wouldn't this remove intended \n's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable pretty print on Document by setting    `doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false)`:

```
@Test
public void testPrettyPrint() {
    String html = "h<span class='cool'>un</span>d";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "");

    System.out.println(doc.body().html());
    System.out.println("==================");
    doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
    System.out.println(doc.body().html());
}
```

Result:

```
h
<span class="cool">un</span>d
==================
h<span class="cool">un</span>d
```